# Flutter App crashes when loading several CachedNetworkImages

Tags: flutter, caching

I currently have a Listview builder where every element in the listview is a cachednetworkimage. So, I could be loading 20 images at a time. However, when this happens, my app could crash. Does anyone have any advice on how to make sure the app doesn't crash? Here is my code

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: this.user.list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: Container(
                  width: screenWidth / 5,
                  height: screenHeight / 3.5,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl:
                          this.user.list[index].picture,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Please include the error. Also are you sure you want `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`?

Comment: @Uroš I cannot find the error, because it just crashes. Is there a way to find the error when it crashes? I also do want the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(). It seems to work in my scenario